# Initial value change on a @Published property from a ViewModel does not trigger animation

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, animation

Basically I need some help trying to toggle an animation the first time a `@Published` property from my ViewModel changes. I was able to come up with a pretty simple minimal reproducible example to show the issue.

What happens is once a State change is triggered from my VM, the animation does not change the first time, but every other subsequent state change does indeed trigger the animation. To show off this issue, I have a circular progress bar and the code is the following:

**The ViewModel**:

```
@MainActor
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var progress: Double = 0.00
    @Published var isLoading: Bool = true
    
    init() {
        //Simply simulates a network call
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.5, repeats: true) { timer in
            self.progress = Double.random(in: 0...1)
            self.isLoading = false
        }
    }
}
```

**The main ContentView:**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if viewModel.isLoading {
                ProgressView()
            } else {
                CircularProgressView(progress: viewModel.progress)
                    .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

**The custom progress View**

```
struct CircularProgressView: View {
    let progress: Double
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Circle()
                .stroke(Color.gray.opacity(0.2), style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 10))
            ProgressView(value: progress, total: 1.0)
                .progressViewStyle(GaugeProgressStyle(progress: progress))
                .contentShape(Rectangle())
            
            Text("\(Int(progress*100.rounded()))")
            
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

**Custom ProgressView style**

```
struct GaugeProgressStyle: ProgressViewStyle {
    let progress: Double
    
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        let fractionCompleted = configuration.fractionCompleted ?? 0

        return ZStack {
            Circle()
                .trim(from: 0, to: fractionCompleted)
                .stroke(Color.blue, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 10, lineCap: .round))
                .rotationEffect(.degrees(-90))
                .animation(.easeOut.speed(0.35), value: progress)
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see on the following video, the very first initial state change that causes the View to change from a regular progress view to the circular one, the progress is not animated, but every other subsequent change does animate fine.

[Video](https://imgur.com/a/RugLmiq)

Any tips?

Comment: You should be using `@StateObject`, not `@ObservedObject` in the `View` where you own the object

Comment: Thank you for the reply :). I just tried swapping for @StateObject but it changes nothing, sadly.